# Query SQLite using uuid returns nothing

Tags: sqlite, uuid

I'm querying a  SQLite db file using the id column, which is UNIQUEIDENTIFIER type.

The two commands are :

```
SELECT * FROM scanned_images WHERE id = cast('5D878B98-71B2-4DEE-BA43-61D11C8EA497' as uniqueidentifier)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM scanned_images WHERE id = '5D878B98-71B2-4DEE-BA43-61D11C8EA497'
```

However, the above commands both returned nothing.

I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM scanned_images WHERE rowid = 1
```

this command returns the correct data.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `uniqueidentifier` data type in SQLite.
According to the rules of type affinity described here in [3.1. Determination Of Column Affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), the column's affinity is `numeric`.
All that this expression does:

```
cast('5D878B98-71B2-4DEE-BA43-61D11C8EA497' as uniqueidentifier)
```

is return `5`.

You should have defined the column's data type as `TEXT`, because you have to treat it like `TEXT` and write the condition:

```
WHERE id = '5D878B98-71B2-4DEE-BA43-61D11C8EA497'
```

or:

```
WHERE id = '(5D878B98-71B2-4DEE-BA43-61D11C8EA497)'
```

if as shown in the image it contains surrounding parentheses.

Comment: This file is get from elsewhere and not generated by me. I have use sqlite library to read this id and it returns an array of 16 uint8. After I convert each interger to hex and then reorder the strings a little bit, and add '-' at right position,  then it became exactly the same uuid string. So the stored datatype should not be string.

Comment: In SQLite you can store any data type in any column. I don't know what manipulation you do before you store the value. But the stored value should be TEXT or maybe BLOB and not uniqueidentifier. Read SQLite's documentation from the link in my answer.

Comment: There is a uuid type in SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: This is about tsql and SQL Server not SQLite.

Comment: I'm not very sure what kind of SQL file it is, but I could open it in SQLite Expert

Comment: There is another post talk about uuid in s

Comment: in SQLite: https://scion.duhs.duke.edu/vespa/project/wiki/DatabaseUuidEfficiency

Comment: The issue here is what you saved in the table. Did you save the value after you converted it to a string? If yes then it is a string. If not then it is BLOB.